# MS Enterprise Library Configuration Application Block removed from 4.1 stack?

Tags: c#, xml

Not sure why the config app block is removed from the latest stack.

Is there a preferred configuration framework out there? I am looking forward to a solution to read/write xml configuration information from C#.

**Edit#1** : Is it true that this functionality is now moved to System.Configuration ? Can we use this to read\write on a custom xml file ( other that web.config or app.config file)

**Edit#2** : Can we use System.Configuration to read/write configuration data in custom config file ( i.e not the application config file or web.config file) ?

Answer (score 3):

**Is it true that this functionality is now moved to System.Configuration?**

Yes, Configuration Application Block from era of .NET 1.1 was moved into System.Configuration as is part of framework from 2.0 version.

Comment: I think that only XML files with custom configuration sections are supported with System.Configuration API.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is back in Ent Lib 5.1, with more features:
http://vaideeswaranr.blogspot.com/2010/08/enterprise-library-50-configuration.html